# phpMyAdmin downloads a file when I try to open it after installing LAMP on my 12.04 LTS system

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I just installed LAMP on my 12.04 LTS system, but whenever I try to run [**phpMyAdmin**](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/), a stranage file downloads. Anyone got a solution for such an issue?

Comment: provide mode information about strange file? is that `*.php` extension file?

Comment: Yes Satish, it has a *.php extension

Comment: If its download file that means apache doesn't know about `php` module. Did you configure apache with php?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me, your apache could have not been started. To check is if it running you can use one the following command (in console/terminal).

```
pgrep apache
```

Any output means it is running, no output means it is not.

If it is not running, start it and then try to access phpMyAdmin again.

To start it:

```
[sudo] /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Where of course, sudo in brackets is optional (but I would recommend using it).

More information would be definitively appreciated. For example what kind of file is downloaded.

Comment: I got apache2 running already, but when I try running phpMyAdmin, that's when the strange file is downloaded.

Comment: @ChrisS what does "strange" file mean? Is it its name, or?

Comment: it actually downloads a file "index.php"